# Django Template: Nested Dictionary "for" tag inside of List "for" tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to be able to iterate over a dictionary while inside of a for loop in a Django template.

For the sake of this sample, consider the following:

```
items_list = [ {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value5', 'key2':'value9'} ]
```

### Method #1:

```
{% for dict in items_list %}
    {% for key,value in dict %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

### Method #2:

```
{% for dict in items_list %}
    {% for node in dict.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ node.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ node.1 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Questions**

- Why does Method #1 not work?  That seems intuitive to me.
- Is the way I'm doing it in Method #2 ok or will that cause problems later on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The .items property should be used in method 1.  Try this:

```
{% for key,value in dict.items %}
```

dict.items() returns a list of key value pairs.  But just dict is a dictionary object.
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: Agreed. Documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for